# Problem in parsing .plist file

Tags: iphone, plist

I've one plist file and I want to parse it and copy it's content into NSArray,and code that I am using for that is.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *fooPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfirstplist.plist"];
NSLog(fooPath);
self.myArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:fooPath] retain];
NSLog(@"%@",myArray);
```

Now problem is very weird, sometime when I print myArray content it prints file data, and sometime it doesn't.

I am facing a same problem even when I use URL as my path.

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:URlPath] retain];
```

what would be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when the array content is not printed? Is there an error, or does the log just show (null)?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you generated the .plist initially, you may run into problems if you try and read it back in as an array. The safest way to read a plist is using the NSPropertyListSerialization class: [Apple Doc.](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class/NSPropertyListSerialization_Class.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

To get the path use

```
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:  @"file-name" ofType:@"plist"];
```

And then use it

```
NSArray *phrase2 = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: plistPath]; 
NSLog (@"%@", phrase2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle]; 

NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:  @"file-name" ofType:@"plist"]; 

NSArray *phrase2 = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: plistPath];

NSLog (@"%@", phrase2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you generating the file with [writeToFile:atomically](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile:atomically:): ? do you check that this returns true?

Answer (score 0):

It was very stupid mistake,
I declared "myarray" properties as "retain and nonatomic" and during parsing operation I am retaining it again,

```
self.myArray = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:URlPath] retain];
```

means I retained it but never released it.that's why that weird problem was there.

Cheers.